# dacpac for xml not supported

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, for-xml, dacpac

When trying to export a data tier application or dacpac from a database that contains functions that use "for xml" every single function and every single object that depends upon that function fails and I am not able to create the dacpac. The wizard reports those objects as not supported.

**Database :** SQL Server 2008 R2

**The error that the functions fail with:**

> [dbo].[fn_FunctionName] () Failed  Depends on object '[XmlData].[value] (UnresolvedEntity)', which does not exist in this database.

**Example query:**

```
declare @XMLColumn xml = '<Example><Node>Test</Node></Example>'

select XmlData.value('.', 'varchar(50)') + ';' 
from @XMLColumn.nodes('/Example/Node') T2(XmlData)
for xml path('')
```

Comment: Bump in the hopes of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it has been a long time but changing your query to the following

```
declare @XMLColumn xml = '<Example><Node>Test</Node></Example>'

select T2.XmlData.value('.', 'varchar(50)') + ';' 
from @XMLColumn.nodes('/Example/Node') T2(XmlData)
for xml path('')
```